# Best practice for advertising routes in BGP

Tags: cisco, routing, bgp, cisco-ios

For connect some customer we want to advertise only one network out and different networks in they provide us. For this I read about route-map and advertising-map feature in Cisco Docu.

For example this one for feature advertis-map:

```
router bgp 2 
 bgp log-neighbor-changes 
 network 128.16.16.0 mask 255.255.255.0 
 neighbor 10.10.10.1 remote-as 1 
 neighbor 10.10.10.1 advertise-map ADVERTISE    
! 
access-list 60 permit 128.16.16.0 0.0.0.255 
!  
route-map ADVERTISE permit 10 
 match ip address 60 
!
```

And this one for the route-map feature:

```
router bgp 2 
 bgp log-neighbor-changes 
 network 128.16.16.0 mask 255.255.255.0 
 neighbor 10.10.10.1 remote-as 1 
 neighbor 10.10.10.1 route-map RED out   
! 
ip prefix-list 1 permit 128.16.16.0/24 
!
route-map RED permit 10 
 match ip address prefix-list 1
```

I have found this booth Solutions to limit the number of networks that announced to customer. The goal is to Create a routing to a BGP Member and advertise only one subnet to the customer, the customer himself advertise one network in our direction? Is it possible with one of this solution and what is the diffrence between this solutions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are conflating two different issues:

Route-maps can act as a policy filter, selecting which prefixes are advertised to neighbors and which are accepted from neighbors.  Advertise-maps allow you to *conditionally* advertise prefixes based on the presence of other prefixes.  They don't control prefixes received from neighbors. Generally, route-maps are simpler to use, unless you really need the conditional feature.

Access-lists and prefix-lists can do the same thing, but prefix-lists are easier to read and allow more precise control over route policies.  In the context of BGP, prefix lists make more intuitive sense, since BGP advertises prefix reachability.

Comment: ok, then I don't need the advertise feature. We have two ISPs they provide us public internet routes. Otherhand we have a few customer they provide us a network we can reach and we want advertise them a network that they can reach. So I try the route-map feature but "sh ip bgp neighbor 10.10.10.1 advertise-routes" show 0 prefixes? Anything I do wrong in the above example?

Comment: Your example is missing the 'out' keyword.  Do you have it in your actual config?  When you type 'show ip route' do you see 128.16.16.0 listed?

Comment: yes out was added in my config. show ip route shows the network as "is directly connected" on the physical port were the endpoint of this network is on this router and the outer network /22 is directly connected, Null0